# Flutter Listivew hashtags show more issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is it possible to do with flutter?
lot of hashtags came from database. If hashtags length more than 3, that time +10more button there, while we click the button. It will expanded to show all the hashtags. Kindly check my two image, you will get an idea.

First Image
[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxKMm.png)

Second Image

[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7UJz.png)

Comment: What you exactly want? I'm not sure sorry, please provide some code of concrete issue.

Comment: Please be clear what you want to ask?

Comment: lot of hashtags came from database. If hashtags length more than 3, that time +10more button there, while we click the button. It will expanded to show all the hashtags. Kindly check my two image, you will get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible!

Here is a simple example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> _hashtags = ["Flutter", "Dart", "Google"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
              height: 50,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _hashtags.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                    child: Text("#${_hashtags[index]}"),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Interactive example](https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b)

Output example:
[image]

Comment: Just check my second image. If i click show more it will give one more line..!!!
Not to be in horizontal scroll, it should be veritcal or else container..!!!

Answer (score 0):

**You can acheive that by doing this**

```
RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                          children: controller.hashtagList.value
                              .map((e) => WidgetSpan(
                                  style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                                      color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16),
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Container(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                        child: Text(
                                          '#${e.hashtag}',
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )))
                              .toList()))
```